# How to access node_modules folder in replit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, replit

I want to copy some files in node_modules folder in replit but it seems that the folder is hidden and i cant create the folder too as it says that the name is reserved. Any solution to add files there ?

Answer (score 0):

Repl.it reserves the node_modules folder for creating the node.js runtime. If you want to install packages, *just reference it* - Repl.it will automatically install the packages and add them to package- and package-lock.json.

Comment: How do I reference it, Please help. I am a beginner. I just want to add files to node_modules folder. I know i am asking you to spoonfeed me but please help as I dont primarily use node.js.

Comment: OK, but why are you referencing it? Is it for packages, or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

To see the content, press `Ctrl + Shift + S` to go to the terminal, then type `ls node_modules` to see the content of the node_modules folder. Sadly, replit reserves this folder and it will be otherwise hidden from view.

Answer (score 0):

In the Files section click on the options bar and in the dropdown select "Show hidden files". You will find the node_modules there.